# SQL Query for Distinctive Values (entries)

Tags: php, sql, mysql, algorithm, distinct-values

lets say i have this query

```
SELECT tags FROM myTABLE;
```

and the result of this comes like

```
CARS 
BIKES
BIKES 
3D 
PHOTOSHOP 
CARS 
3D 
ANIMALS 
NATURE 
PHOTOSHOP
```

what i want to do is not reapeat any word in Result... only fetch the distinctive entries once...

like

```
CARS 
BIKES 
3D 
PHOTOSHOP 
ANIMALS 
NATURE
```

could this be done with only SQL... if not then can anybody suggest an easy algo for this...

p.s i am using PHP & mySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use the distinct keyword.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tags FROM myTABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DISTINCT`](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-distinct-sql-tutorial/):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(tags) FROM myTABLE;
```

---

> The SQL DISTINCT command used along
>   with the SELECT keyword retrieves only
>   unique data entries depending on the
>   column list you have specified after
>   it.

**More Info:**

- http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-distinct-sql-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

use the keyword distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT tags FROM myTABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT(tags) FROM myTABLE;

Answer (score 0):

Know more about the DISTINCT clause here:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/20/sql-server-distinct-keyword-usage-and-common-discussion/

Comment: I read this page briefly and i dont understand the concept of selecting a single distinct column in a resultset, it just does not make any sense to me. SELECT DISTINCT A, <nondistinct> B from tbl would just be weird, to get more rows you need to duplicate the value for A for each variation of B on A. using GROUP BY, you can specify which aggregate function to apply on B (and more columns), like MIN(), MAX(), AVG() etc. Distinct on anything but the whole row is just .. weird!